# has_one relationship is resulting in ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError , what am I missing here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I feel like I am overlooking something obvious here.  I can create a story model, and a category model, but I can't relate a story to a category.

Here is how I reproduce the error:

```
s = Story.new(title: "test", picture_url: "www.google.com") 
c = Category.last
s.category = c
```

error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `story_id'

Story model

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :story_roles
 has_one :category
end
```

Story migration file

```
class CreateStories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :stories do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :picture_url
      t.integer :category_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
  validates_presence_of :body
end
```

Category migration

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `t.references :story` in your migration. The belongs_to method on category requires `story_id`.

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.references :story
      t.string :body
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your story model, change `has_one :category` to `belongs_to :category`.  A rule of thumb is if you have a foreign key for a model, you declare the association as `belongs_to`.  In this example, you have `category_id` in the story model so you use `belongs_to :category` in the story model.  This makes perfect sense since a story should really belong to a category and a category `has_many stories`.

Comment: The confusion for me is,  the story is suppose to only have one category, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing at first but you'll get used to it.  Remember that when you have a `has_many` relationship, it's partner on the other end should be `belongs_to`.  a category has_many stories so a story should belong_to a category.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **foreign_key** `story_id` in your `Category` Model. Add that column in your categories table and migrate it.That would resolve your issue.

**Note:** Before migrating the changes,roll back the previous migration.

OR

The best way is what **@bekicot** suggested. Just add `t.references :story`. This includes `story_id`,so that it will be added to your categories table by default.